# Squishy vectors

Tags: code-golf, array

If we have a list of integers we can "squish" one of them by:

- decrementing it
- replacing adjacent values with its new value

For example in this list:

```
[1,2,8,3,6]
```

If we squish the `8` we get:

```
[1,7,7,7,6]
```

The question is:

**Given a starting array, what is the largest we can make its sum by repeatedly squishing values?**

For example if we are given:

```
[1,5,1,1,9,1]
```

Here the starting sum is `18` but if we squish the `5` or the `9` it will go up.  Squishing anything else will make it go down so we will squish them.

```
[4,4,4,8,8,8]
```

Now the sum is `36`, but it can still go up, if we squish the left-most `8` it will increase to `37`.

```
[4,4,7,7,7,8]
```

We can squish the left-most `7` but it won't change the sum.  If we go back and try some other things we will find that the best sum possible is in fact `37`.

So the answer here is `37`.

### Task

Given a list of two or more positive integers as input give the maximum sum that can be attained by repeated squishing.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the goal is to minimize the size of your source code as measured in bytes.

### Test cases

```
[2,2,2] -> 6
[4,5] -> 9
[4,6] -> 10
[4,4,6] -> 14
[4,6,5] -> 15
[1,1,9] -> 21
[1,1,1,9] -> 25
[1,8,1,9,1] -> 38
[1,10] -> 18
[1,5,1,1,9,1] -> 37
[9,1,1,1] -> 25
[3,6,7,8,1] -> 31
```

Comment: In what order do we squish? `[1,8,1,9,1]` when squishing 8 and 9, it will collide in the middle element. Do we squish the max first on the first one?

Comment: @12944qwerty That's the challenge there.  You need to find out what the best order to squish them is.

Comment: @12944qwerty there are no simultaneous squishes, the example in the question is shortened for... brevity

Comment: Suggested test case: `[1,6,7,9,1]`.  If I worked this correctly, the first step actually decreases the sum.

Comment: @Nitrodon Squishing 6 or 9 will increase the sum...

Comment: @12944qwerty That 6 was originally a 5, but then I realized you didn't need to squish the 5 for the best sum.  I'm sure there's some way to get the result I was after.  Maybe `[3,6,7,9,1]`?

Comment: @Nitrodon I think `[3,6,7,8,1]` should work.  To start `8` is the only number which increases the sum. Squishing it gives `[3,6,7,7,7]` where now no number can increase the sum.  But if you squish `6` then `8` you get `[5,5,7,7,7]` which is 1 more.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>77</s>  76 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @tsh*

```javascript
f=(a,s=0)=>Math.max(...a.map((p,i)=>(s+=p,--p)&&f(a.map(q=>i*i--<2?p:q))),s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc5LDoIwEAbgvadgRabaFkqAiLF4Ak9gWDQIWoO0WGK8fSUKGh4zm0n@LzNzE09h8ofULanVubC25CCw4T7i6VG0V3oXL6CUim7QABrLLgCz4RoTopHrlvCNGp7KtSRkHxz0rkEIYYNsrmqjqoJW6gIlnALcdeZ8CiHH85x4NSEhjnowkGRO4glh/tz8VW/ChT2/Y72JpoZhhpORCdiSGVRvlvb42fjnrX0D) (some test cases removed)

[Faster version with a cache](https://tio.run/##bc/RDoIgFAbg@57CKwd1QDEta2FP0BM4L1hl2UopXOuidzcsrGnAxs7Gt//fOYm7UNtbIWtSVrt90@QcCVDcxzzJU5Hx9nk@N6I@0ot4IEqp0INESEKhDVITLoEQiV03R5@vK0@KcUHIKljL5RVjDAo326pU1XlPz9UB5SgNQN/MeR@MHc9zZqMBCSEyoCOLfzIbEOb/m58yJrTkfMuMiYaGAYNFzwTMZjpljCUnbg2wrDPT2JLjZ/29LCb6tOkkkzMfmqnea972/bpY8wI) (87 bytes, solving all test cases almost instantly)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (                 // f is a recursive function taking:
  a,                  //   a[] = input array
  s = 0               //   s = sum of the array, computed in the main loop
) =>                  //
Math.max(             // return the maximum of ...
  ...a.map((p, i) =>  //   for each value p at position i in a[]:
    (                 //
      s += p,         //     update the sum
      --p             //     decrement p
    ) &&              //     if p is not equal to 0:
    f(                //       do a recursive call:
      a.map(q =>      //         pass a new array where the items a[i-1],
        i * i-- < 2 ? //         a[i] and a[i+1] are set to p and
          p           //         everything else is left unchanged
        :             //         we do this by testing i² < 2 and
          q           //         decrementing i after each iteration
      )               //
    )                 //       end of recursive call
  ),                  //   end of map()
  s                   //   add the sum of the current array
)                     // end of Math.max()
```

Comment: `f=(a,s=0)=>Math.max(...a.map((p,i)=>(s+=p,--p)&&f(a.map(q=>i*i--<2?p:q))),s)`

Comment: How does the algorithm work?  Its hard to verify this since it seems to take forever to work on some pretty small cases.

Comment: @WheatWizard It really just brute forces all solutions. [Here](https://tio.run/##bc/LcsIgFAbgfZ@ClUJ7ICEaL22xT@ATOFkwaVLxErA4nTraZ4@opBkjsDkD3/z/nJX8kTb/VmZPK/1Z1HUpsAQrYlgXByHZSqsK96M@IWKWy3xZLNx7JtrxdJrL/ZJt5S9mjEk3GIwNKOexfREGKDWk1yvx7WsnZupZUfqefJjXHSEELKmvaUig49/bU64rqzcF2@gvXOJFAu5m6HoIQVGERl0yhNSDhkwfyahDePxoWuXNMJDzX@ZN2jUcOEzvTMJDplHeBHImFwM8a8xgEsiJs/u9Aia9tbkknzPumoHba3zpa7t4fQY) is an optimized version with a cache which solves all test cases almost instantly.

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>37</s> 35 bytes

```
ftnqZ^!"G@!"tt@)q@3:H-+GfX&(]]v!sX>
```

Brute force approach. It tries all possible sequences of up to *n*−1 squishes, where *n* is the length of the input. This is sufficient, because at that point all numbers will be equal and further squishing will decrease the sum.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P60krzAqTlHJ3UFRqaTEQbPQwdjKQ1fbPS1CTSM2tkyxOMLu//9oIwUgjAUA) Or [verify all test cases except the longest one](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D@tJK8wKk5Ryd1BUamkxEGz0MHYykNX2z0tQk0jNrZMsTjC7r9LVEXI/2gjBSCM5Yo2UTAFk2ZgEkabgUUNFQwVLKE0jGUBYikYQkQNgJQlWBIkYAzUZg5SEAsA).

#### How it works

```
ftnqZ^     % Cartesian power of [1 2 ... n] with exponent n-1, where n is input length
!"         % For each Cartesian tuple
  G        %   Push input
  @!"      %   For each number k in the current tuple
    t      %     Duplicate the partially squished input array (*)
    t@)q   %     Push its k-th entry minus 1 (**)
    @3:H-+ %     Push [k-1 k k+1]
    GfX&   %     Intersection with [1 2 ... n]. This handles the edges (***)
    (      %     Write (**) at entries (***) of (*)
  ]        %   End
]          % End
v          % Vertically concatenate all partially (or totally) squished arrays
!s         % Sum of each array
X>         % Maximum. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ā<ZиæεvDyè<2Ý<y+ǝ]Oà
```

Brute-force approach, so pretty slow the larger the input-list is.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SKNN1IUdh5ed21rmUnl4hU2lTaXd0R3H58b6H17w/3@0oQ4IWsYCAA) or [verify the shortest few test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeWhlf@PNNpEXdhxeNm5rYfWFZe5VB5eYWN0eK5NpfbxubW1/ocX/Nf5Hx1tomMaqwMkzYCkoY6hAZAy0gFCsCBEGEiCFQGldSyhNIRlCWYZgsUsQGJgtjFQvTmIDxY3hagG8mIB).

**Explanation:**

```python
ā                 # Push a list in the range [1,input-length]
 <                # Decrease each by 1 to make the range [0,length)
  Z               # Push the maximum/length-1 (without popping the list)
   и              # Repeat the list that many times
    æ             # Get the powerset of this list
     ε            # Map over each inner list:
      v           #  Foreach over each index `y`:
       D          #   Duplicate the current list
                  #   (which will be the implicit input in the first iteration)
        yè        #   Pop the copy, and get its `y`'th value
          <       #   Decrease it by 1
           2Ý     #   Push list [0,1,2]
             <    #   Decrease each to [-1,0,1]
              y+  #   Add `y` to each: [y-1,y,y+1]
                ǝ #   Insert the value-1 at these indices
                  #   (ignoring those that are out of bounds)
     ]            # Close both the inner loop and outer map
      O           # Sum each inner list
       à          # Pop and push the maximum
                  # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

`2Ý<y+` could alternatively be `y<y>Ÿ` or `y<DÌŸ` for the same byte-count.

Comment: _(ignoring those that are out of bounds)_ How convenient :-) Handling that took me a few bytes in MATL

Comment: @LuisMendo Yeah, almost all 05AB1E builtins would have modular indexing, but the `ǝ` not for whatever reason. I don't mind, though. This isn't the first time it was useful, and should I happen to need modular indexing for it in a challenge, I could add a few straight-forward bytes to modulo the length. :)

Comment: This doesn't terminate for the last test case or [1,1,1,1,9] (maybe all size 5+ inputs).

Comment: @DarrenSmith Yeah, I know. `ā<Zи` increases the length exponentially and `æ` increases that exponentially on top of it. And then I even ignore the fact that there is an additional inner loop `v`, and out-of-bounds `ǝ` aren't too fast either. The `ā<Zиæε` alone will give [A053763](https://oeis.org/A053763) (\$a(n)=2^{n^2-n}\$) amount of iterations, so for an input of length 5 this is little over 1 million iterations (excluding the additional inner iterations of `v`) and for an input of length 6 this is 1.07 billion iterations.. :/

Comment: @DarrenSmith Including inner `v` loop, there will be \$a(n)=2^{(n-1)^2+n-2}\times((n-1)^2+n-1)+1\$ amount of iterations in total, so 24,577 iterations for inputs of length 4; 10,485,761 iterations for inputs of length 5; 16,106,127,361 iterations for inputs of length 6; etc.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>116</s> 103 bytes

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 89 bytes** by replacing two `function` appearances with `\`s.

*Edit: -13 bytes thanks to [@Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe).*

```r
function(v)max(combn(rep(0:l,l),l<-sum(v|1),function(x){for(i in x)if(i)v[i-1:-1]=v[i]-1;sum(v[1:l])}))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/?fbclid=IwAR1y_64hplcTdrMjeL36xvNoB3snqIeac8Rc_xFuIgIjIelzFruTN2lVu5s##TY7NCoNADITvPsWClwR2wfivrX0R8dBKFxb8KbaK0PbZrdpdlVwy30yGdJPMJtk35Uu1DQxYX0co2/rWQHd/gJNWvEJencWzr2H4EPItO@Jbth0opho2opKgcMiVoFRQkc1bIei0XuWUVgV@EScJJbh8HkSbiQsLrYX4PNA60TrUmhwNDsg3me2KghURJ55o5JJlMwMPONhwvGBO2vBiU@GY0niLBv@OPRxpK1kN2ssX6M2fRUu9SdP0Aw)

Explanation outline:

1. Generate all possible sequences of indices to squish (`0` indicating "skip") - of length equal to length of input; possibly with duplicates, which don't matter.
2. Use `combn`'s `FUN` to apply on each one the squishings in a `for` loop.
3. During squishing, luckily we need to account only for the overflowing indices on the right (writing to index `0` is a no-op), hence the indexing in `sum(v[1:l])`.
4. Take `max` of all of the possible sums.

Comment: `combn` has a `FUN` argument which does your `apply` for you: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/?fbclid=IwAR1y_64hplcTdrMjeL36xvNoB3snqIeac8Rc_xFuIgIjIelzFruTN2lVu5s##TY7RCoJAEEXf@4oFX2ZgBKey1LAfCR9KWljQVawWofr2TW1XZZ/uuXcP01mZW/nS5VM1GgxV@eNVg/kwYn3toWzqm4bu3kKUVVQhVTSPe3zLpgMllBY9KgkKzaWtlQYVchbyMC9yc1FFyKdJil9EK6GELQ0PMRDhWRw2I9lT7HLq8sFljhxYob3fzL84nhATU@rQljeB8HCF4xknIyZ2xS7xishLk3ka/x3L@OiqdCp4kY9wN1x2HPV@zfYH "R – Try It Online")

Comment: And another byte by [in-lining `l`](https://tio.run/?fbclid=IwAR1y_64hplcTdrMjeL36xvNoB3snqIeac8Rc_xFuIgIjIelzFruTN2lVu5s##TY7LCoMwEEX3fkWgmxlIwKlv@/iR4qKVBgImim1FaPvtVm2iMqt77oNpB3ka5MuUT1Ub6FBfeyhrfTPQ3hvw84pXyKujeLw0dB9CvmR7fMu6BcWUYT0qCQq7S6OVASUoFzQWi1N3UYWgw9zGL@IgoYQ9Hw9xx8SZxd5EQh5ZnVkdW02@BRsUuszSomhGxIlnFu3J2zEHNzhacDphTtYIUjfhu9F0iUb/jTWcWCubDVrHJxiMnyXTvEvT8AM)

Comment: [-3 more](https://tio.run/?fbclid=IwAR1y_64hplcTdrMjeL36xvNoB3snqIeac8Rc_xFuIgIjIelzFruTN2lVu5s##TY7NCoNADITvPsWClwR2wfivrX0R8dBKFxb8KbaK0PbZrdpdlVwy30yGdJPMJtk35Uu1DQxYX0co2/rWQHd/gJNWvEJencWzr2H4EPItO@Jbth0opho2opKgcMiVoFRQkc1bIei0XuWUVgV@EScJJbh8HkSbiQsLrYX4PNA60TrUmhwNDsg3me2KghURJ55o5JJlMwMPONhwvGBO2vBiU@GY0niLBv@OPRxpK1kN2ssX6M2fRUu9SdP0Aw)

Comment: @Giuseppe, thanks! Now I will always try to check docs for `FUN` arguments in unexpected places.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>Yowch, it took quite some effort circumventing Jelly's, usually useful, modular indexing nature!</sup>

```
J;-ṗLị@’¥’r‘RƇƲ}¦ƒ€⁸§Ṁ
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of positive integers that yields the maximal sum reachable (only revisiting previously squashed indices if better for the golf).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUEAvv9qZWxsef//Sjst4bmXTOG7i0DigJnCpeKAmXLigJhSxofGsn3CpsaS4oKs4oG4wqfhuYD///9bMSw4LDEsOSwxXQ)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/LWvfhzuk@D3d3OzxqmHloKZAoetQwI@hY@7FNtYeWHZv0qGnNo8Ydh5Y/3Nnw/3A7kPf/f3S0kQ4QxipAgbKCrp2CGZdOtImOKVwQKmwJFjZDFzY0AIsjy0DETSDqkQyCiJsCxQ11DHUsUcWNDKHiCBmIOES9BUhcxzAWLm5sAVFvEIvmHoi4KcQksA6IenOguCVY1BDDfGOgO81BdiCZb8gVCwA).

#### How?

```
J;-ṗLị@’¥’r‘RƇƲ}¦ƒ€⁸§Ṁ - Link: list of integers, A
J                      - range of length of A -> [1,2,...,length(A)]
  -                    - literal -1
 ;                     - concatenate -> [1,2,...,length(A),-1] -> our alphabet
    L                  - length of A
   ṗ                   - Cartesian power (all words of length length(A) with our alphabet)
                  €    - for each word
                   ⁸   - ...using A as the right argument:
                 ƒ     -   reduce [A]+word by:
                ¦      -     sparse application
               }       -     ...to indices: using the right argument (next integer of word):
              Ʋ        -       last four links as a monad - f(I=integer):
         ’             -         decrement I
           ‘           -         increment I
          r            -         inclusive range -> [I-1, I, I+1]
             Ƈ         -         filer keep those (of [I-1, I, I+1]) for which:
            R          -           range (truthy for positive integers)
        ¥              -     ...apply: last two links as a dyad - f(current state, I):
      @                -       with swapped arguments:
     ị                 -         index into -> our squish value
       ’               -       decrement
                    §  - sums
                     Ṁ - maximum
```

Comment: My approach to circumventing cyclic indexing was the reverse: instead of keeping those elements of `[I-1, I , I+1]` that intersect with the range, I kept those elements of the range whose difference with `I` was insignificant. I know Jelly has a built-in for insignificant but I don't know whether that helps you out here.

Comment: Nice thought, the code I've written uses `¦` which applies a link (function) to the provided indices\* so it'd be a significant change - maybe there's a way to do it that saves bytes using insignificant index difference, but editing a list in-place is usually more golfy with `¦` (otherwise one ends up partitioning and joining) so probably not.

\* FWIW, `¦` isn't fully modular like indexing into a list with `ị` it allows updates from index `-length(A)-1` (leftmost), through `0` (the rightmost element) and `1` (leftmost again), up to `length(A)` (rightmost again), hence the `RƇ`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 105 bytes

```python
f=lambda l,i=0:0<sum(l[i:])and max(f((l[:i][:-1]+[l[i]-1]*(3-(i<1))+l[i+2:])[:len(l)]),f(l,i+1))or sum(l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1BbsMgEEX3nAJlNVNjyzhOlKA4F0EsqGyrIwG2DK2a07uYVhWb9/4fZtZX@ljCed/nwVn/PlruBA2tah/x04PTpAzaMHJvv2GGHCgyWtXSVDqXJsMbnGugh0SsclJ1@YNWbgrg0KCYIe@rcrlsvGzEnfy6bInHV2RszrHjFA5rYhopNNtkR0dhioCKcRLL4O0K05d1wjVxdZTgVD9PiIyvG4UElI8QigV33RteP3nPdCfyK3JluheXgvcDrwVle/C/9aX5G5MXpqWQ4l6sk8Xa3@r2Aw)

The squishing is surprisingly annoying, due to one-off errors near the edges. Bruteforce solution, which stops only when non-positive numbers have been encountered.

The function calls itself two times. Once with the index `i` squished, and once with `i` incremented (but the list remains unsquished). The maximum of those calls are returned.

There are two edge cases, one is when `i` is outside the list, and another one when we feel enough squishing has been done. We  can check for both cases with `0<sum(l[i:])`. When this becomes less than one it can be for two reasons. One is that `i` is equal to the length of the list, which means that the sum of the empty list is taken (which is zero). Another possibility is that the elements of `l` are so squished that some of them are zero or even negative. Clearly at this point we have done more than enough squishing and can stop.

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 171 bytes

```python
L={};g=lambda l,i:0<sum(l[i:])and max(f((l[:i][:-1]+[l[i]-1]*(3-(i<1))+l[i+2:])[:len(l)]),f(l,i+1))or sum(l)
def f(l,i=0):L[(i,*l)]=L.get((i,*l))or g(l,i);return L[(i,*l)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3LjoMgFIb3PAXpCioaqbUXWvsEfQPigonYngTRKJ1MM5lndwBnDJv/8p2f4e2evS3m@V59/1welVHdR6OwYSDy6/TqiJEgaqpsgzv1RVriAwG1FCmvE@nL2ostKVICV05p4pNk5w@kMNoSQ2vKWuLXEl/2I46LFDW6xTGucirukgDberS6Zw/tyOIC/QgIvYzavUaLV26GbuhHh6f3hFDrOYPBBpdNrgGbjVo1BqyeCBUIA@urTg1EfyrDTDYNBhzZpLcNpQgPI1jnZ1sClPV0ljvmX43TGz4guWdllOcgD1HyPOjV7WPzh/ESSc44O0e344tbfWxPwTMek@IUiXw5jqZcDv6BI5LnmPB1ovDfHcPMQvBf)

Just a memoized version of the first submission. Is able to calculate all testcases in reasonable time.

Comment: I'm attempting to run it but it keeps saying that the program is terminated and exceeded the 60 second time limit (with the link you have)

Comment: @12944qwerty It was just due to the algorithm being very slow. I've removed the more demanding test cases

Comment: [104 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY3BbsMgEETvfAXKabfGlnGcKEFxfgRxoLKtrgTYMrRqvt7FtKr2Mm9mNLu@0scSzvs@D87699FyJ2hoVfuInx6cJmXQhpF7@w0zZEOR0VKZSufM1NK8wbkGekjEKjtVl/tauSmAQ4NihjxX5XDZeBnEnfy6bInHV2RszrbjFA5qYhopNNtkR0dhioCKcRLL4O0K05d1wjVxdZTgVD9PiIyvG4UElJ8QigV33RteP3nPdCfyFbgy3YtLkfdDXouU7aH/qS/JX01emJZCinuhThZqf6PbDw) maybe? i did [:-1] to [1:] i think its wrong but idk

Comment: @DialFrost, yeah I don't see how it would be correct

Answer (score 3):

## Python3, 505 bytes:

```py
S=sum
M=max
def f(n):
 if any(i>1 for i in n):
  yield n;d={}
  for i in range(len(n)):
   if n[i]>1:
    k,j=n[:],0
    k[i]-=1
    if i:k[i-1]=k[i];j+=1
    if i+1<len(k):k[i+1]=k[i];j+=1
    d[j]=d.get(j,[])+[(n[i],k)]
  if 2 in d:
   T=[],[]
   for _,y in sorted(d[2],key=lambda x:x[0],reverse=True):
    T[S(y)>S(n)].append(y)
   for i in T[1]:yield from f(i)
   if T[0]:yield from f(M(T[0],key=S))
   if M([t for t,_ in d[2]])==M(n):return
  if 1 in d:
   yield from f(M(d[1],key=lambda x:x[0])[1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVNNb@IwED3Xv8LiUlsYhKG0kK75B@wFbq6FjOx0DYkTOaEiWu1vZ8dOyX5UOWTevDfPM5O47toflV@s6nC77URzKdFWlPqKjM1xTjzNEHY51r4jbsNxXgXssPM4EbhztjDYvxrx8xfAgQ3av1tSWA8GSRg9vHRqwxPCZ3YSXmaKzXoI1ETwFIPSZZCYcCVi/vU0/osZ82/R9kyjZPxFYuRJCTN9ty05ManoWJJ4LDtThZLBPLZnUhN7IRVoYhgbP7Auck0VWmuIkXOosp0odHk0Gl@zq5wphoP9sKGxYh8utp8M7@WOdHSzg1nVVNe19Qbw3TbtYy@5yvpl5aEqYbGOfm5lD7b/UlsSc@nwHb3LtkS2ya9lhzQC9KeoENv4iYJtL8H3A/I/A/7naqCJryNRyNJbI0ajEZJzBo/Ckw1@RvKJLVO4juFzCvksxgN6SsynjC@R5IyzdUJz3qMBJ3YVMeMps1glxawvTmDZF9wFL0iuU4YPFgs47iXa9AqOYtuurOGjYd20aNh47orWBvK98pbhZtrUhWvJ45t/jP/jg2b4iAUudU2gagqcDbo42A9dMOzu6ngE6NFDHZxvSZnFi0FyomlaI9wVCt6XksT3kd5@Aw)

A bit of optimization to produce all the test case results quickly.

---

## Python3, 392 bytes:

@AnttiP has very cleverly taken my original solution above and has condensed it down, and although slower due to its leveraging of speculative execution, it is much shorter:

```py
S=sum
M=max
def f(n):
 if M(n)<2:return
 yield n;d,T=[[]]*3,[[],[]]
 for i in range(len(n)):
  k=n[:];j=i>0;k[i]-=1;k[i-j]=k[i]
  if k[i+1:]:k[i+1]=k[i];j+=1
  if n[i]>1:d[j]+=[(n[i],k)]
 for i in[T[S(y)>S(n)].append(y)for _,y in sorted(d[2])[::-1]]and T[1]:yield from f(i)
 if T[0]:yield from f(M(T[0],key=S))
 if d[2]and M([t for t,_ in d[2]])==M(n):return
 if d[1]:yield from f(M(d[1])[1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVLBjtowED2vv8LisnYxCMOyC6bmD@gFbq6FvIrTGhITOaFqvp7OOLtR1QpF8968NzO2mabvft7iatOkx@Oo23tNDrp2v0nhS1qyyBWhoaQHQF@XKvnuniKhffBVQeOuECdtjLVfVgKCAERoeUs00BBpcvGHZ5WPUItt6FVHo@zuosN@sbuaYGdaYpxdrEYKFhgFaCqVVTkOwu4y1XJQI9C9VIW52Kk2DKm48r/GmpM5sp7vjzDVzl3T@FgAR/ksejxXe0udL1hhlpYbpWbSWhcLejLSquFiZbrVcPnA891PZvGPcGCYE1ff6yMfTNgNuxyY6fJZOnHGYZi3XGt8wPH5sl/@1xRzHL9HqyeTCTFLAT9LZ3v6SsyLWGe4RfiaoVwgHtlLVj5sck2MFFJsM1vKgY08qxvkQubMapMdi6E4k/VQ8Gl4I2abM3JssYJxb9hmcEiCxw51Ay9MXduRcRfKUHU@sW@36AVt521ThY49f4/PuBlPTtB3qmntGgZVc9B8ctXZ/3KVoOHTjSPAT56aFGLHaoV7ykrmeP4nYHU59L7XDOM7f/wB)

Comment: `T={1:[],0:[]}` can just be `T=[],[]`

Comment: @pxeger Thanks, updated

Comment: Shaved a couple of bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDBboMwDL3zFTkma5ia9jKFhT/gBDfLqpAStkAJKKXS@HoWgzRN2yGyn5/znu15XT6ncH2b47bV5vEcs8qM7VdmXcc6HoTOmO9YlbL3i45uecaQsdW7u2WhsLIxAIgvV5mCTFnGuikyz3xgsQ0fjt9dSH9Jhg0mgMaiN748FwN4zI2imPdoCKaWZJWyk9Ko93gQRX8y6mBDgqXSFno8GeAE5SB@2UIDNV9FWSdXfG3n2QWbMNE3udJcjykuznILFxSgda4Q22BZAwr1sVgXpzEt78W@ewPnP0TFqSYHt5paHE2kRioVh2WfZZE3MqM6CmPogD/n2/vVP1GqCXrb9g0 "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online"). I assume that `key=lambda x:x[0]` is not required (it doesn't matter which order elements with same `x[0]` are picked).

Comment: Most of the golfs I did were related to speculative execution. The idea is that you can execute code, and check the if-statements later. Although it defeats the purpose of having fast code a bit; the golfed version is 10x slower.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 47 bytes

```
Ｆ⊖ΦＥＸ⊕ＬθＬθ↨ι⊕Ｌθ⌊ι«≔⮌θηＦιＵＭη⎇‹¹↔⁻μκλ⊖§ηκ⊞υΣη»Ｉ⌈υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/LSgNBEDxnv6KPvdAegqCCpzUSCBhY1FvIYbLbZobMw8wjRsRvH2f2Yg65VXdVV1cNUvjBCZ3zh/OAzzx4Nmwjj7hUOrLHtfjE3n0VtLL/5AvbfZR4bFuCS/wkAqMiuK6tirWyyiSDqo7w08y6ENTe4iuf2JfjY9HI9rGZTYFUCyXAwhkj7IiS4J29Ff67mIaAc4JuF5xOkbH4poCG4DC90QSXZbq4siOfq0Plq3@fgsRE8FbCyLr5bXqvbMSFCLHUPk8xUxXnvNnc0h3d0wPNt9t8c9J/) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ⊖ΦＥＸ⊕ＬθＬθ↨ι⊕Ｌθ⌊ι«
```

Generate all possible squishing sequences of length up to the length of the input.

```
≔⮌θη
```

Make a copy of the input.

```
ＦιＵＭη⎇‹¹↔⁻μκλ⊖§ηκ
```

Perform all of the squishing steps.

```
⊞υΣη
```

Save the sum of the result.

```
»Ｉ⌈υ
```

Output the maximum sum.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) List::Util, 112 bytes

```perl
sub f{my$s=sum@_;max$s,map f(@$_),grep{$s-2<sum@$_}map{@a=(0,@_,0);@a[$_..$_+2]=($_[$_]-1)x3;[@a[1..@_]]}0..$#_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5fT4MwFMXf@RQ32gUaO0LZ2B@wyrvGvegTkgZdIcSxIYU4Q/jsWMARNE2Tnt859/bkojg4bXwqDC0ACGyiTgjsDlYAIenZkjg92U7IqifUmqARLqe531nqjJASSrY9tOkfOOJpdtNhQntjsZnmrWHxlDnDlkt8PVrb3qD/1y9Uv3X3xZAf6uBaA8i@DZQSJDDzEfd6gBIWGz5KcSfzIj2W8dVMAoA45@K9FHsXZvZe6eRUXp7pMa@UUFOvxysCSDCGknv99KG7@tPuGXYPekfVTTyt0Sop4DGVpeu@lOkBPr@MLDqDrDLstbJ6g7hWNSRTwOeespAkWZRDV4tjkhQir5Gc27ddAPFGebUfMcMiPicW9vwoQNw0Eb@xQ2YgrlQ4p/i88AJlUdP0eRg2lkpc86ZtfwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 103 bytes

Thanks to Kevin Cruijssen for -2 bytes!

it's not a lambda!

Pretty self-explanatory, pads with zero to avoid edge cases while copying x to y, squashes a digit in y by assignment, recurses if the digit is not less than 0. The sum is calculated on the input vector to each call and updated if any recursive call returns a larger result. This sum (`s`) is returned after trying all the digits.

```python
def f(x):
 s=sum(y:=[0,*x,i:=0])
 for v in x:y[i:i+3]=[v-1]*3;s=max(s,v<0 or f(y[1:-1]));i+=1
 return s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BjoMgFEX3fMVLV9CikWqblg79EeLCRM28BJEANfr1DjKTyduck3tz89wWv2dbP5zf934YYaQrkwSCCp@JblLpip9XjlJVLSMwzh4WQAur3DRKvNSt0ksh2nP9CmrqVhr48lVBqo1000KmiLEXXpQg4If48RbCjpObfYSwBUKORXMsJitD7NGWfuh6g3YI9PgE@ZyGHR2WznBTBmcw0lPxPrH0j/NoI0U@UmR8ZrtuWije0BB95emy3Ilu@C3j88B7RlEd/G9NTv5q4ka04II/s11Ftuo3evwA)

Comment: Thanks! Wow it's easy to miss the most obvious stuff

Comment: Why use a pre-release version of 3.8 when it was released 2 years ago?

Comment: @Holloway It's the latest Python version available at Try It Online, which hasn't been updated in a couple of years.

Comment: @Holloway I'm using the := assignment expression so I have to use at least 3.8, thus the pre-release. This should work on any python >= 3.8. These days you can use pxeger's [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/) to use a newer python. I often use others' python answers as a starting point and in this case I used AnttiP's which was already on TIO (check out the blatantly obvious identical test code in my answer and AnttiP's).

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>40</s> <s>39</s> 33 bytes

*-1 thanks to [Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334/unrelated-string); -6 thanks to [Fatalize](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41723/fatalize)*

```
~b~k{{~c₃↺{Ṫ∋₁-₁ℕgj₃}ʰ↻c↰|}bk+}ᶠ⌉
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/vy6pLru6ui75UVPzo7Zd1Q93rnrU0f2oqVEXiB@1TE3PAkrUntrwqG138qO2DTW1SdnatQ@3LXjU0/n/f7ShjqGOWez/CAA)

Brute force solution. *V e r y   s l o w*. For testing purposes, I suggest changing `ℕ` to `ℕ₁`, which helps significantly (but still not enough to solve most of the test cases in less than 60 seconds).

#### Explanation

This solution comes in layers, like an onion. Also like an onion, working on it made me want to cry.

```
~b              "Unbehead" the input list, prepending an uninitialized variable
  ~k            Do the same at the other end ("unknife")
    {...}ᶠ      Find all ways to satisfy this predicate (see next section)
          ⌉     Take the maximum

{...}           Apply this predicate (see next section)
     bk         Remove the first and last elements of the resulting list
       +        Sum

|               EITHER return the list unchanged, OR:
 ~c₃            Partition the list into three sublists
    ↺           Rotate so that the middle sublist is at the beginning
     {...}ʰ     Apply this predicate (see next section) to that sublist
           ↻    Rotate so that the middle sublist is back in the middle
            c   Concatenate back together
             ↰  Call the current predicate recursively on the result

Ṫ               The sublist must be a three-element list
 ∋₁             Get the element at index 1
   -₁           Subtract 1
     ℕ          Assert that this is a nonnegative integer
      g         Wrap it in a singleton list
       j₃       Join three copies of that list into a single 3-element list
```

Comment: 34 bytes without breaking anything (I hope), by using `ʰ` instead of a fork: [`,0↔,0{{~c₃↺{Ṫbh-₁ℕgj₃}ʰ↻c↰|}bk+}ᶠ⌉`](https://tio.run/##AVAAr/9icmFjaHlsb2cy//8sMOKGlCwwe3t@Y@KCg@KGunvhuapiaC3igoHihJVnauKCg33KsOKGu2PihrB8fWJrK33htqDijIn//1sxLDEsNl3/WA)

Comment: You can also use `~b~k` instead of `,0↔,0` to shave one more byte.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 157 bytes

```
f=lambda l:max([f((l[:max(i-1,0)]+[v-1]*(3-(0==i%(len(l)-1)))+l[i+2:])*((i>0 and v>l[i-1]+1)or(i<len(l)-1 and v>l[i+1]+1)))for i,v in enumerate(l)]+[sum(l)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZLfbpswFMbveQoLaZJPcSacNG2DRqVdrA@w9Y5alRfMZskYBE7UPX3qPwRMVQ0uMJ9/5zvHH/T/zN9O7y6XplS8/V1zpIqWv@GqwVhVfik3lOTAsuq8oewG7zY4L0v5BSuhsYINBYBMVTLbFgxuMJaPOeK6RudHK9qKjEI3YPntii@bmd8EaLoBSXJGUiOhT60YuBEWtR3HU@sWcDFiNK9HPooRlahKkL1wtSX2ZuQOyCTckj0jh@j1jhGaR@9BuY0JV0L3s0IJJQdGtnSlBC2mHpxGKCO7h5jMrVks7EOxB@9n/eBVurLc2VHuna0lXXOWJD0fR6n/2BM/DyeRNFwqUb@6KHwKLAnBOWGd3ZIWFN5evPXiaERty9xeRZmXB3EU8uzlxhdVOQO/0w9SG5w@O2tnhFKUodHY7wgr4MX8mKyLGbk2@0j@nLot5LU//Kdp6lIQdYpkEx2jXGYXypEhnDQYWVR35lM85OG7zek@cWsx63HMX3nfC13bUyeJNZ1Kinja70r5TFH4O6dpIXFjrcBfXStiMvQh0zOISzTxFACXdw)

Finds all the moves that would result in at least 1 element increasing value, then recursively tests those moves and returns the maximum value achieved or the original value.